# How can I delete a Firebase document with a condition

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm trying to delete a card item with vuetify, and the associated Firebase document

I built the code so this is the HTML snippet

```
      <div>
        <v-card-title
        class="headline"
        v-text="item.listName"
        ></v-card-title>
        <v-row>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn
              text
              color="primary accent-4"
            >
              Liste Abrufen
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
          <v-icon
            small
            @click="deleteItem(item, item.listName)"
          >
            mdi-delete
          </v-icon>
        </v-row>
      </div>
```

and my idea was to remove a single one so and also direct in the database

```
deleteItem (item, id) {

          const index = this.shoppingLists.indexOf(item)
          let res = confirm('Möchtest Du den Einkaufsschnippsel wirklich Löschen?') && this.shoppingLists.splice(index, 1)
          if (res == true) {
            firebase.db.collection('shoppingList').doc(id).delete()
          }
        }
```

Only the card is removed, but not the database entry

But if I write the database part into the first line of the function, it will be deleted!

This One:

```
firebase.db.collection('shoppingList').doc(id).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct Function.
res got the wrong data type!

```
deleteItem (item, id) {

          const index = this.shoppingLists.indexOf(item)
          let res = confirm('Möchtest Du den Einkaufsschnippsel wirklich Löschen?')
          if (res == true) {
            this.shoppingLists.splice(index, 1)
            firebase.db.collection('shoppingList').doc(id).delete()
          }
        }
```